# Not able to access object from data in ViewModel

Tags: extjs, viewmodel

Am trying to fetch the `persondetails` details into `enableButton` method.
Am aware that we can achieve this by simply adding `key` and `value` to `data` object. 
But my question here is, is there any way to store data into `persondetails` and fetch it?

If I specify as below and bind accordingly, then its wok fine.

```
data: {
 firstname: '',
 lastname: ''
}

bind: {
  value: '{lastname}'
 },
```

Here is the code:

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        Ext.define('MyApp.view.TestViewModel', {
            extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',

            alias: 'viewmodel.userinfo',

            data: {
                persondetails:{
                    firstname: '',
                    lastname: ''
                }
            },
            formulas: {
                enableButton: function(get){
                    debugger;
                    if(get('firstname')!=='' && get('lastname')!=='' ){
                        return true;
                    }else{
                        return false;
                    }
                },
                fullName: function(get){
                    if(get('firstname')!=='' && get('lastname')!=='' ){
                        return get('firstname') + ' ' + get('lastname');
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            title: 'Contact Info',
            width: 500,
            bodyPadding: 10,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            viewModel:{
                type:'userinfo'
            },
            items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'firstname',
                emptyText: 'Enter First Name',
                bind: {
                  value: '{persondetails.firstname}'
                },
            }, {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'lastname',
                emptyText: 'Enter Last Name',
                bind: {
                  value: '{persondetails.lastname}'
                },
            }, {
                xtype: 'button',
                reference: 'clickme',
                disabled: true,
                bind: {
                    disabled: '{!enableButton}'
                },
                text: 'Click',
                listeners: {
                    click: function(){
                        alert('{fullName}');
                    }
                }
            }, {
                xtype: 'displayfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Full Name',
                bind: {
                    value: '{fullName}'
                }
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

I have created a fiddle [Example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/33dc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/modern/Ext.app.ViewModel.html)

> When a direct bind is made and the bound property is an object, by
>   default the binding callback is only called when that reference
>   changes. This is the most efficient way to understand a bind of this
>   type, but sometimes you may need to be notified if any of the
>   properties of that object change.
>
> To do this, we create a "deep bind":

In other words, if a object changes its properties, the viewmodel will not notify these changes (although their properties are changed correctly).

If you need to listen this changes, you need to use deep binding

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        Ext.define('MyApp.view.TestViewModel', {
            extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',

            alias: 'viewmodel.userinfo',

            data: {
                persondetails: {
                    firstname: '',
                    lastname: ''
                }
            },
            formulas: {
                enableButton: {
                    bind: {
                        bindTo: '{persondetails}',
                        deep: true // listen to any change in personaldetails
                    },    
                    get: function (data) {
                        return data.firstname && data.lastname
                    }
                },
                fullName: {
                    bind: {
                        bindTo: '{persondetails}',
                        deep: true // listen to any change in personaldetails
                    },    
                    get: function (data) {
                        return data.firstname + ' ' + data.lastname
                    }
                },
            }
        });
        Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            title: 'Contact Info',
            width: 500,
            bodyPadding: 10,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            viewModel:{
                type:'userinfo'
            },
            items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'firstname',
                emptyText: 'Enter First Name',
                bind: {
                  value: '{persondetails.firstname}'
                },
            }, {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'lastname',
                emptyText: 'Enter Last Name',
                bind: {
                  value: '{persondetails.lastname}'
                },
            }, {
                xtype: 'button',
                reference: 'clickme',
                disabled: true,
                bind: {
                    disabled: '{!enableButton}'
                },
                text: 'Click',
                listeners: {
                    click: function(){
                        alert('{fullName}');
                    }
                }
            }, {
                xtype: 'displayfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Full Name',
                bind: {
                    value: '{fullName}'
                }
            }]
        });
    }
});
```